# How can one create horizontal tree view using CSS and HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, html

thanks for your interest, first I believe image is worth thousand word, so here you go 
[image: This is kind of what I am trying to achieve]

Unfortunately I am not in possession of mouse right now, so its drawn using IBM TrackPoint, but the main idea should be clear.
I called it horizontal tree because usually tree view is vertical, you would only see one directory on one line and on the left hand side of the directory name would be just vertical lines showing how deeply nested this directory is. I am trying to have "directories" listed next to each other.

Think of it as of algorithm diagram with IFs and ENDIFs and they will always have exactly two outputs or inputs.

**Now, I am trying to construct this with basic HTML elements and CSS and I thought at first that it will be piece of cake but it isn't, I spent whole afternoon on it with no luck. It will be generated by JS dynamically so I am trying to avoid tables. There could me any number of IFs, there will be exactly same amount of ENDIFs. There will be any number of other basic cells. The whole structure starts with one cell and ends with one cell**

Here is html that should generate similiar picture:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>IFs and ENDIFs</title>
<style>
ul, li, div{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    }
ul.left{
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    list-style-type:none;
    width: 150px;
    float:left;
    }
ul.right{
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    list-style-type:none;
    width: 150px;
    float:left;
    }

}
li.parent{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color:#CC9;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    min-width: 350px;
    display:block;
    overflow-style:marquee-block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root">
    <ul>
        <li class="parent">
            <div class="label">1</div>
            <ul class="left">
                <li>    
                    <div class="label">1.L1</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="label">1.L2</div>
                </li>
                <li class="parent">
                    <div class="label">1.L3</div>
                    <ul class="left">
                        <li>    
                            <div class="label">1.L3.L1</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="right">
                        <li>    
                            <div class="label">1.L3.R1</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="label">1.L3.R2</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right">
                <li>
                    <div class="label">1.R1</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="label">1.R2</div>
                </li>
                <li class="parent">
                    <div class="label">1.R3</div>
                    <ul class="left">
                        <li>    
                            <div class="label">1.R3.L1</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="label">1.R3.L2</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="label">1.R3.L3</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="label">1.R3.L4</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="right">
                        <li>    
                            <div class="label">1.R3.R1</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="label">1.R3.R2</div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="label">2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="label">3</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what it looks like so far :( (nothing near the result i hope for, also this is probably 7th iteration of me trying to figure this out) So if anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.
[image]

Comment: Try hiring someone. It seems like your after someone doing this for you. What do you need help with exactly? Which part are you struggling with. The Javascript logic? The styling?

Comment: MY bad, I am struggling with floating the elements next to each other in case they are children. As in my example at the bottom, I managed to get Children "1.L" and "1.R" of parent "1" next to each other, but I had no luck with the ones deeper.

But thanks, for telling me to hire someone. I am trying to do something, for myself, I am not making money, also I want to figure out where am I making mistake. After staring at my laptop for 14 hours (first 12 spent on something that works :)) straight I might be overlooking some basic stuff. Anyways, isn't this site based on helping each other?

Comment: That's not a tree. It's a cyclic graph.

Comment: This will do it for you. just download and use it : [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Horizontal_JS_Tree.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Horizontal_JS_Tree.aspx)

Comment: @mehaase - Thanks! I was wondering what was the proper name of this structure. Now I can search for more info about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML a linear data structure, but your graph you are trying to recreate isn't linear. While it is possible, it's not necessarily trivial.

You should avoid using float, because nested floats are a bit difficult to control. `inline-block` is probably a better solution here, however support is flaky in older browsers.

Have a look at an example I made, maybe you can build on that: http://jsfiddle.net/uf5uM/

Comment: Thanks you so much! I almost gave up and started thinking about a different way to achive the goal, but your solution seems solid.

Comment: No seriously I had to come back to thank you once more, I can't believe I haven't tried inline-blocks. It so infrequently used display property that I don't even think about it. Now I just have to make sure there is no white space in between them LIs and I am all set :) Thanks again, you rock.